# JsonSchema Property Dependencies from Model

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonschema

Well, I understand how property [dependency](http://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#dependencies) works in JSON-schema and I can successfully put together a JSON-schema that works fine in [JsonSchemaValidator](http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/) :

```
{
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
        "ServerName" : {
            "type" : "string"
        },
        "Username" : {
            "type" : "string"
        },
        "Password" : {
            "type" : "string"
        }
    },
    "dependencies" : {
        "Username" : ["ServerName"],
        "Password" : ["ServerName"]
    }
}
```

In the above JSON-schema the idea is to accept Username or Password only when there is a ServerName.

My problem is how to form the model in C# so that the dependency is recognized in the same way as Required attribute.

What I was expecting was something like this:

```
public class TestModel
  {
    public string ServerName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Dependency = new [] {"ServerName"})]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Dependency = new[] { "ServerName" })]
    public string Password { get; set; }
  }
```

If there is no attribute for that then I need to know how to add that to the schema using the JSON-schema methods.

I know that there is a property called Dependencies on JSON-schema and I tried it but it has no effect and I'm not sure how to use it properly.

I tried something like below but it didn't change the schema at all:

```
  ...
  var jsonSchemaGenerator = new JSchemaGenerator();
  var schema = jsonSchemaGenerator.Generate(typeof(TestModel));
  schema.Dependencies.Add("Password", "ServerName");
  schema.Dependencies.Add("Username", "ServerName");
  var schemaJson = schema.ToString();
  ...
```

Any idea?

Comment: Why do you expect to be able to express something like that with attributes on your model? A JSON schema operates on an already serialized JSON. You could use Json.NET to validate your already serialized model against a JSON schema. Maybe I misunderstand your question and goal.

Comment: Thanks @DarinDimitrov for the comment. The goal is to go Model First. That means we do the model in C# and then generate the schema based on that model. Currently I wasn't able to find a way to do dependency like I've done required fields.